# Stuck in BL2 and don’t know what to do

Tags: borderlands-2

I have been playing borderlands 2 recently for about 2 weeks. I am mainly sticking with my Zer0 build who is at level 40 (almost 41) but I have a level 10 Axton and Salvador. I have already played all of the DLCs except for commander Lillith’s, which I almost finished.

That being said, when I unlocked TVHM, I was excited to use it, then realized that it was tough. I wasn’t really about that. Sure I got more EXP for killing things but even then, that was about it.

I was wondering if there was any tips that anyone had for possibly getting levels faster and better guns (best is my 834x17 New and Improved Shotgun Surpreme) other than just doing TVHM.

If there is any way, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest thing is to check that your weapons are a reasonable level compared to enemies. Lower level weapons might have been fine in normal, but as you said TVHM is more challenging.

Make sure you are using the different [elemental weapons properly](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Elemental_Damage#Borderlands_2). In normal mode for example fire deals 150% damage to flesh (red health) but only 75% damage to shields (blue) or armor (yellow). In TVHM these are increased further to 175% for flesh and 40% for shields and armor. As for other damage types, shock weapons deal bonus damage to shield, and corrosive will deal bonus damage to armor. On top of that, using slag on a target makes them take double damage from all non-slag damage types.

An easy way to farm some weapons and EXP would be to repeat the Warrior fight on normal mode. Since you've completed the DLC's you can also do tier 3 fights at the campaign of carnage.

Comment: Sounds great! I’ll try to farm the warrior more, and tier 3 fights sound like something to do to. Thanks dude.